# How do you replace audio at a given timestamp with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) library to take two FLAC files and replace the audio in **File A** with the audio in **File B** at a given timestamp.

For example if **File B** was to be played at 00:02 and was a second long, playing the output it would be `(00:00-0:01) File A Audio -> (00:02-0:03) File B Audio -> (00:04-...) File A Audio`

To do this, I have tried the following

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.flac -i replacement.flac -acodec copy -ss 2 -to 3 -write_xing 0 result.flac
```

But this only produces the original audio between the specified timestamps.

Is there any way to achieve this within ffmpeg?

Comment: Do you know the durations of A and B?

Comment: @Gyan Yeah they should be known - and at the very least it is gaurenteed File B is shorter than File A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical method to do this would be the concat demuxer, but there are issues with FLAC extraction with duration header in the output, so you can use

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.flac -i replacement.flac \
  -filter_complex "[0]atrim=0:2[Apre];[0]atrim=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[Apost];\
                   [Apre][1][Apost]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" out.flac
```

Where `2` is the insertion point in seconds, and `5` is the insertion point + B's duration.

Comment: Outstanding - That works brilliantly! Thank you for your help